# Schema error missing field image and name

Tags: schema

so I'm running and audit and I'm getting an error: Missing field "image" and Missing field "name" to my schema code. I'm new to schema, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Google's Rich Results Test website is highlight this code:

```
<span class="footer-content-name" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"><strong>Shanley Pump and Equipment, Inc.</strong></span>
```

[Schema error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQKfZ.jpg)

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `itemtype="name"` and `itemtype="image"` tags.

Example from https://schema.org/Product:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="name">Kenmore White 17" Microwave</span>
  <img itemprop="image" src="kenmore-microwave-17in.jpg" alt='Kenmore 17" Microwave' />
</div>
```